# storing the count down timer value in android

Tags: java, android

As the Count Down timer pauses, how would you store the value? 
which then when you want to resume the timer eventually will restart a new timer 
with this stored value. I am so confused how to hold the value. 
I am a beginner in java and android programming. 
could any one guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Android has inbuilt class for count down i.e. **CountDownTimer** class . You can use this.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: yes, my count down timer looks like that but I dont know how to store the value in a variable so that as I pause the timer and resume it, the stored value will be in the new timer. I did before makes it reset not resume e.g. from (mm:ss) 10:00 to 8:45. what I did is it backs to 10:00 instead of 8:45. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Countdown timer doesn't have a `pause()` method. Workaround that i can think off is try getting the time at `onTick()`.

Answer (score 0):

So you have an application displaying count down timr,  and  like  that it continues countdown from very same moment after being paused?   In this case you have to save your 
remaining time in some location in onPause() method ( best location would be shared preference )

Or do you like to have real countdown time and fire some event  after it expires, even if your application is inactive?   Then schedule an alarm at desired time,  and store  scheduled time somewhere (shared preferences would be ideal).  In this case you can forget keeping time yourself,  just update UI periodically  using real time and stored time difference